# tips on demo setup

Tags: android

This is a general question. If i were to demo an app [for HoneyComb 3.0 running on Xoom] in development to someone remotely, what are my options?

The app is a heavily media (video) oriented
The person demo-ing to does not have a Xoom device or any honeycomb running tablet yet
Cannot send the apk to be installed on a phone since the app was targeted for tablet form features

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest to use some MS Sharepoint or Goto Meeting tool to share your window and demo the app from your machine.

Comment: But the emulator does not support video :(

Comment: Well, you can download the app on your XOOM and do a video conferencing or web cam conferencing.

Comment: yeah. that's what i am doing now. was wondering if there were better ways. is there a way to "record" the application in action on the device? i.e when i am using the app, is there a method to have all the UI recorded on device (something running in the background and capturing what's happening on the screen)? Thanks

Comment: Record the video when you are using the app if you have camcorder and then upload the video on youtube.